# Using a third party library (sbpl)

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I've built and installed a library called [sbpl](http://sbpl.net/) on linux\ubuntu. After installing i have the following files:

`usr/local/include/sbpl` (have a bunch of files here including a `headers.h` file)

`usr/local/lib` has a `libsbpl.so` file

Now I'm having some trouble compiling a simple program:

**yus.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sbpl/headers.h> 

int main()
{
  EnvironmentType type;
  return 0;
}
```

Using these commands to compile i get errors:

```
$ g++ yus.cpp -Iusr/local/include/sbpl   gives the following error 
"error: 'EnvironmentType' was not declared in this scope"

$ g++ yus.cpp -L.-lsbpl   gives the same error as above
```

How does one go about compiling and linking the library correctly?

Comment: try `g++ yus.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lsbpl`

Comment: Still gives me the same error :(

Comment: Is it `/usr/local/include/` or `usr/local/include`? If its `usr/local/include` try `g++ yus.cpp -Iusr/local/include -Lusr/local/lib -lsbpl`

Comment: And is `EnviromentType` defined in the headers? I dont believe too much once in this test file: https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl/blob/master/src/test/main.cpp `EnviromentType` is defined inside the main file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the definition of `enum EnvironmentType` from main.cpp to headers.h and then run `g++ yus.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lsbpl`